# how I can make the mesh invisible and keep the fire?

Tags: mesh, materials, export, physics, fire

[image]

how I can make the mesh invisible and keep the fire ?

Comment: if rocket + fire are one unique object you can separate the fire from the rocket: go in Edit mode, select the fire with the L key, press P to Separate. Now the fire is an object by itself. You can hide the rocket with H. Does it answer?

Comment: thank you for helping plz check my last replay

Answer (score 0):

If your mesh is one piece, and you don't want to work destructively,just go in the edit mode and select the unrequired vertices and hit H on keyboard to hide it
You can unhide it by alt+H

If your mesh in seperate,just click on eye button in the outlined

If you want your mesh to be seperate,select the unrequired vertices and press P to seperate it as other mesh

Comment: As you shown in the suggestion,you have to click on the eye button of second mesh,also in order to hide something in render, click on the funnel icon at top of the outliner and click on the camera,this will enable another option in front of eye button which is used to toggle render visibility